# Pessoal quem poder me ajudar, sou iniciante em javascript,

Tags: javascript, dom, localstorage

Queria fazer com que os a quantidade de clicks fosse armazenado no localStorage, e quando voltasse o numero de clicks continuasse onde parou. Tentei fazendo assim, porém no `alert` só mostra `NaN`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        document.body.appendChild(p);

    $(document).ready(function(){

         var cout = localStorage.getItem('cout') || 0;

            $("#btnCount").click(function(){
                cout = parseInt(cout)+1;
                $('p').html(cout);
                alert(cout);
                localStorage.setItem('cout',cout);
            });         
    });    
    </script>
    <button type="button" id="btnCount">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.setAttribute('id','num');
        document.body.appendChild(p);

    $(document).ready(function(){


        cout = localStorage.getItem('cout');
        cout = parseInt(cout) || 0; 

            $("#btnCount").click(function(){
                cout = cout+1;
                $('p').html(cout);
                // alert(cout);
                localStorage.setItem('cout',cout);
            });         
    });
```

Comment: Isto é uma resposta à sua pergunta ou mais informações que deveriam pertencer à pergunta ?